# Node class in C++

Tags: c++

A newbie in C++. I am trying to create a node class (and not struct) in c++. And practice some various trees implementations.

My header file

```
#ifndef  NODE_H
#define NODE_H
class Node{
private:
    Node *left,*right;
    int data;
    Node(){}
public:
    Node(int data);
};
#endif
```

class def

```
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node(int data) {
    this->data = data;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
}
```

My test:

```
#include "Node.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Node n = new Node(2);

}
```

error:
 In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:

```
/home/fraz/ClionProjects/algorithms/BinaryTest.cpp:3:24: error: invalid conversion from ‘Node*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     Node n = new Node(2);
                        ^
In file included from /home/mohit/ClionProjects/algorithms/BinaryTest.cpp:1:0:
/home/fraz/ClionProjects/algorithms/Node.h:9:5: note: initializing argument 1 of ‘Node::Node(int)’
     Node(int data);
     ^
```

Yeah, I have a long way to go.

Comment: Try `Node* n = new Node(2);`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/ might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Node(2);
```

This returns a `Node*`, not a `Node`. The error message is confusing because initial assignment like this can be handled by the single-parameter constructor. So it's looking for a `Node(Node*)` constructor to feed that `Node*` to but the only constructor it can see is `Node(int)` and there's no way to *implicitly* convert `Node*` to `int`.

How you fix this depends on what you want:

If you want a pointer to a `Node` (most likely), so you can copy that pointer around, then you want to write:

```
Node* n = new Node(2);
```

If instead you want to create a `Node` object that is local to the function and not dynamically allocated, you want:

```
Node n(2);
```